# Compile and Run command line projects from Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, command-line

I am working on a piece of software which I compile using this command in `Terminal`:

```
gcc -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox Main.m Buffer.m WavFileReader.m WavFileCreator.m LowPassFilter.m Snippet.m Blender.m EffectsFilter.m -o /Users/ericbrotto/Desktop/audio
```

I then run the executable also via `Terminal`.

How can I do this from an Xcode project using the `Run` button which builds and run applications.

Comment: write a make file, import it to Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to start by creating a project with a command line target.   Then, once you have done that, remove the files that it adds by default to the project and then add your files in to the project, making sure to check the target when you do so.

You will want to think a little bit about the location of the files, just so that they make sense for you and aren't too far off of where Xcode would normally put them.

You may or may not find the execution during the run phase to be satisfactory, but I have found it fine for small test programs and things that run without user input.   Otherwise, you probably want to do the run in Terminal to get better I/O.